# Error with the below script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am performing the below operation. I am getting the error and unable to find what the error is.Could any one help me finding it.
a)  Check for the availability of DESTINATION data base. If it is not exist, create the data base and move the tables to the data base.
b)  If the table exists in the DESTINATION data base then no process required for the table.

```
if db_id('Destination')is null
begin
Create database Destination
select * into TabDestination from [Source].[dbo].[TabSource]
end 
else
begin
use Destination
go
if('TabDestination' in (select name from sys.objects where type = 'u'))
insert into TabDestination select * from [Source].[dbo].[TabSource]
end
```

I am getting fallowing error

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Database 'Destination' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'end'.
```

Comment: Please get in the habit of specifying the version of SQL Server you're using. sql-server is a good start, but solutions can vary depending on the actual version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems here:

- After `Create database Destination` you need to use that database before you do the `select * into TabDestination...` as you will create `TabDestination` in some other DB.
- The `Go` in the middle of the `begin...end` block won't work.
- To specify your database for the inserts to TabDesitination you'd be better to use the fully qualified name of the table than calling `Use`, eg `Insert Destiation.dbo.TabDestination...`
- You need to use `If Exists (select...` for the second if statement.
- Because your Database may not exists when the script compiles, a lot of the sql needs to be exec'd dynamically.

So your script could be re-written as:

```
if db_id('Destination')is null
begin
    Create database Destination    
    exec ('select * into Destination.dbo.TabDestination from [Source].[dbo].[TabSource]')
end 
else
begin

    if exists (select name from Destination.sys.objects where name = 'TabDestination' and type = 'u')
    insert into Destination.dbo.TabDestination select * from [Source].[dbo].[TabSource]

end
```

Comment: when i execute the above querry. I am able to see DB created but table is not created.

Comment: I believe that you only need the dynamic SQL inside the first block, not the second. Also since we know `TabDestination` is a table, why not just check `Destination.sys.tables` so you can avoid the pesky additional `WHERE` clause? That said it is probably safer to also check the schema prefix.

Comment: @Aaron - about the dynamic bit. Although you only need the dynamic to run the code - ie to take those two lines and run them, if the DB isn't already there then the second two lines will fail to validate, even when they aren't going to get run.

Comment: That's not true, did you try it? I could run the batch (with the only dynamic SQL part being the select into), first when the database doesn't exist, and again when it does, and both times I get 90+ rows inserted. At least I tested this against 2008, 2008R2 and Denali. It will only fail if you explicitly mention columns, the database DOES exist, and the columns don't exist - but not just because the database doesn't exist.

Comment: @Aaron - interesting - as you say - it does actually run. The inline validation in SQL 2008 SSMS does draw wiggly red lines under the statements though - I guess I made the mistake of believing what I was told! ;-)

Comment: @Aaron, about sys.objects: Fair comment -  I tend to use information_schema.tables myself. I didn't want to make his script look nothing like how it started, so I left as much as I could.

Comment: @Shine. Running the code works fine for me. Are you changing anything when you run it? Might you have odd priviledges? Did you try Aarons modification in his answer? - the DB might already exist in which case your script wouldn't create the table.

Comment: I very rarely trust IntelliSense - it often puts those squiggly lines under things that work just fine at runtime. My biggest annoyance is synonyms, which I use quite a bit.

Comment: If the script runs fine but the table is not created, it may make sense to add `PRINT` commands so you can see which part of the code is being executed. e.g. `PRINT 'Creating database';`, `PRINT 'SELECTING INTO new table';`, `PRINT 'INSERTING INTO existing table';`, etc. This is debugging 101.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with the [`USE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx), from the documentation:

> USE is executed at both compile and execution time...

If the database specified doesn't exist at compile time then the query will fail.  You can see this by trying to run the following query:

```
IF 1 = 2
BEGIN
    USE NonexistantDatabase
END
```

This query fails despite the fact that the `USE` statement is never executed.

You should instead change your query to use database qualified names, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Destination.dbo.Table SELECT * FROM Source.dbo.Table
```

Comment: Fair point, but there's a lot of other things going on aswell.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @Jon Egerton's answer, however there is one case you've neglected to cover: the database exists but the table does not.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * 
    INTO Destination.dbo.TabDestination 
    FROM Source.dbo.TabSource;';

IF DB_ID('Destination') IS NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating database...';
    CREATE DATABASE Destination;
    PRINT 'Selecting into new table...';
    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Destination.sys.tables WHERE schema_id = 1 
        AND name = N'TabDestination')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Inserting into existing table...';
        INSERT Destination.dbo.TabDestination SELECT * FROM Source.dbo.TabSource;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Selecting into new table...';
        EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
    END
END
```

**EDIT**

Added `PRINT` statements for debugging purposes, as I suggested in the follow-up to @Jon's answer.

Comment: Thaq :-) It was easy to debugg with the way you explained

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get rid of the GO command, its a batch separator so it breaks your begin/end. Oh and you can't use USE like that either.